# 'checked' state remains static in Chrome

Tags: checkbox, google-chrome-devtools

I distinctly recall that when clicking a checkbox in Chrome the "checked" status under Developer Tools \ Elements would appear/disappear to match the state of the checkbox, complete with a nice little transition to bring one's attention to the change.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<body>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" checked>
    </label>
</body>
```

[image: checked status is out-of-sync]

Now clicking the checkbox updates its visual representation, but the status remain constant at the initialization value. How can I recover the previous behavior? (I'm right now at Chrome 62.0.)

Comment: It sounds like a bug. Can you try out a couple of different sites and confirm that the `checked` attribute doesn't show up on any of them? If it's broken across all these sites, then please file a bug at `https://crbug.com`.

Comment: I'm not sure specifically about showing the property in the Chrome devtools, but the `checked` *attribute* does not change when you change the `checked` *property* of the input, and therefore the DOM is not actually updated.  Perhaps Chrome fudged it, but I think it is misleading to do so, since the DOM does not actually change.  See more about attributes vs properties in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003819/what-is-the-difference-between-properties-and-attributes-in-html